# Kotlin/Native Could not find :kotlin-native-prebuilt-windows-x86_64:1.8.21

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I am attempting to load an application that has KMM and multiple modules , I get this error when I am trying to build.
I tried upgrading gradle , I tried upgrading java , installed KMM plugins in android studio but still the same issue .

```
Could not find :kotlin-native-prebuilt-windows-x86_64:1.8.21.
```

Required by:
project :utils:auth-utils

Comment: Check workaround from here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-49268